# Scheme function that returns a function

Tags: scheme

I need to write a scheme function that returns as a function which then takes another argument, eg a list and in turn return the desired result. In this example `(c?r "arg")` would return -- `(car(cdr`  -- which then subsequently takes the list argument to return 2

```
> ((c?r "ar") '(1 2 3 4))
2
> ((c?r "ara") '((1 2) 3 4))
2
```

The problem I have is how can I return a function that accepts another arg in petite?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you might write such a function:

```
(define (c?r cmds)
  (lambda (lst)
    (let recur ((cmds (string->list cmds)))
      (if (null? cmds)
          lst
          (case (car cmds)
            ((#\a) (car (recur (cdr cmds))))
            ((#\d) (cdr (recur (cdr cmds))))
            (else (recur (cdr cmds))))))))
```

Note that I'm using `d` to signify `cdr`, not `r` (which makes no sense, to me). You can also write this more succinctly using `string-fold-right` (requires [SRFI 13](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-13/srfi-13.html)):

```
(define (c?r cmds)
  (lambda (lst)
    (string-fold-right (lambda (cmd x)
                         (case cmd
                           ((#\a) (car x))
                           ((#\d) (cdr x))
                           (else x)))
                       lst cmds)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add my playing with this. Uses [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#fold).

```
(import (rnrs)
        (only (srfi :1) fold)) ;; require fold from SRFI-1

(define (c?r str)
  (define ops (reverse (string->list str)))
  (lambda (lst)
    (fold (lambda (x acc)
            ((if (eq? x #\a) car cdr) ; choose car or cdr for application
             acc))
          lst
          ops)))
```

Its very similar to Chris' version (more the previous `fold-right`) but I do the `reverse`so i can use `fold` in the returned procedure. I choose which of `car` or `cdr` to call by looking at the character.

**EDIT**

Here is an alternative version with much more preprocessing. It uses `tail-ref` and `list-tail` as shortcuts when there are runs of #\d's.

```
(define (c?r str)
  (let loop ((druns 0) (ops (string->list str)) (funs '()))
    (cond ((null? ops) 
           (let ((funs (reverse 
                        (if (zero? druns)
                            funs 
                            (cons (lambda (x) 
                                    (list-tail x druns)) 
                                  funs)))))
             (lambda (lst)
               (fold (lambda (fun lst)
                       (fun lst))
                     lst
                     funs))))
          ((eq? (car ops) #\d) (loop (+ druns 1) (cdr ops) funs))
          ((= druns 0)         (loop 0 (cdr ops) (cons car funs)))
          (else (loop 0 (cdr ops) (cons (lambda (x) 
                                          (list-ref x druns)) 
                                        funs))))))
```

This can be made even simpler in #!racket. we skip the `reverse` and just do `(apply compose1 funs)`.

```
(define (c?r str)
  (let loop ((druns 0) (ops (string->list str)) (funs '()))
    (cond ((null? ops) 
           (let ((funs (if (zero? druns)
                           funs 
                           (cons (lambda (x) 
                                   (list-tail x druns)) 
                                 funs))))
             (apply compose1 funs)))
          ((eq? (car ops) #\d) (loop (+ druns 1) (cdr ops) funs))
          ((= druns 0)         (loop 0 (cdr ops) (cons car funs)))
          (else (loop 0 (cdr ops) (cons (lambda (x) 
                                          (list-ref x druns)) 
                                        funs))))))
```

Comment: `list-ref` and `list-tail`? Not sure how one might use these to solve this particular problem. I guess I didn't understand what you meant by "compress". :-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Something like this.. After writing this I wonder how Racket have implemented `compose1`

Comment: @Sylwester it's roughly equivalent to `(define (my-compose1 . fs)
  (foldr (lambda (f g) (lambda (x) (f (g x)))) identity fs))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a `compose` procedure:

```
(define (compose funs . args)
  (if (null? funs)
      (apply values args)
      (compose (cdr funs) (apply (car funs) args))))

(compose (list cdr car) '(1 2 3 4))
=> 2
```

`c?r` can be defined in terms of `compose` like so:

```
(define (c?r funs)
  (lambda (e) 
    (compose 
     (map
      (lambda (f) (if (char=? f #\a) car cdr))
      (reverse (string->list funs)))
     e)))
```

then

```
((c?r "ar") '(1 2 3 4))
=> 2
((c?r "ara") '((1 2) 3 4))
=> 2
```